# Put GridView in Edit Mode Programmatically with ASP MERMERSHIP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need Put GridView in Edit Mode Programmatically when editing ROLES in ASP MERMERSHIP.
Could you provide me some examples? I am not able to write the appropriate EVENTS to display the right EDIT TEMPLATE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but a GridView is designed to have only one row in edit mode at any one time.

You can specificy programmatically which row should be in edit mode with:

```
  YourGridView.EditIndex = rowIndex;
```

where rowIndex is an int representing the row number (-1 being none).

Select the edit index and re-bind the GridView.